# bulbs in series with individual power

Tags: dc, series

Three lamps (with individual power of 30W , 40W and 50W ) are connected in series to a source of 100V .
What is the voltage to the terminals of the 40W lamp ?

Comment: Looks like homework, smells like homework ...

Comment: sure it is,but i spent a lot of time trying to solve it,that why i need your help guys. that question is basic,can you give basic answer?

Comment: Sure its basic, so show what you've done so far & where you're stuck.

Comment: If these are incandescent lamps, rated for equal voltage, the 30W bulb will probably have near 100V across it.

Comment: We don't just do your homework for you here.

Comment: Kind of a silly question, If you assume they are all rated at the same voltage then you could use the power to "predict" the resistance of each bulb.. (You do know the equation for the power dissipated by a resistor, right?) and go from there.  In practice bulb resistance is highly non-linear with voltage.  (I'm talking of incandescent bulbs.)

Comment: Homework.  Initial effort not demonstrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: You may notice that I'm making a different assumption from some other answers, just because it leads to an answer. The question appears to be a bit ambiguous or misleading.

The total power is 120W, so you can easily calculate the total current for a supply voltage of 100V.

Given the current you can easily determine the voltages on each bulb, since the product of voltage and current is known (the power). Of course the current through each bulb in a series string must be the same.

Comment: 120W would be true if the lamps were in parallel, but the OP asked about **serial**.

Comment: @DoxyLover 30+40+50W = 120W. The question does not say anything about ratings it says those are the individual powers.

Comment: @DoxyLover But it specifically says that the lamp *powers* are 30W, 40W and 50W. If you connect 120VDC across them individually they'd obviously dissipate considerably more power. That's my stated interpretation. I am not going to imagine words that are not there.

Comment: Ok, re-reading the question one more time, I agree that it is badly written and it's not clear if he's saying that the lamps are in series or the lamps are in series with the voltage source. Please edit your answer so I can remove my down-vote.

Comment: I like this answer as it tackles the way you normally think about lamps and powers and connecting them.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the three lamps are normally supposed to be connected to the same voltage in parallel, the resistances of each bulb is inversely proportional to the power of the bulb (since \$P={{E^2}\over R}\$ means \$R={{E^2}\over P}\$).

From there we can determine each of the resistances in relation to their normal voltage, the total resistance of all three bulbs, and how much the single bulb resistance drops in relation to the whole series chain.

Comment: I thought we avoided doing people's homework for them, particularly when there's been no effort shown ...

Comment: @brhans: Good call.

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information and it may not be that clear so I'm giving it as an answer. A 30 watt bulb might need 30 volts to produce 30 watts i.e. it has a resistance of 30 ohms and takes 1 amp. On the other hand it might be a 300 volt bulb and take 100mA hence it will have a resistance of 3000 ohms.

That's the basic problem with the question and, secondary is the potential underpowering of lamps means the filament resistance is significantly lower than on full power and nobody would be foolish enough to assume that all three bulbs in series would have proprtionally the same lower resistance when operated at lower powers.